# CSS advanced minimizing (optimizing)

Tags: css

My question is about advanced optimizing Cascade Style Sheets (CSS) files for production.

What a the most new and completed (ready to be used in live projects) css optimizers/minimizers that provide not just removing of white spaces and line breaks but also advanced features as removing excessive attributes, merging similar classes and so on..

There are some good online tools like:
http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor

But I would like to see available implementations to be included in automatic building.

Comment: `merging similar classes` How do you propose that works? See something like yahoo http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: Well, I did not invent it. You may easily have excessive parts in your final css code especially if you use dynamic languages as SASS ans LESS.

Comment: Merging similar classes... only a human could do that, unless you've got `.class { color: red; }` and `.class { text-decoration: underline' }` right next to each other? Also removing excessive attributes, care to give an example? As far as I see it this too is highly subjective. It's all well and good chasing those last few kb, but is it really worth it? Instead, look into the performance of your selectors.

Comment: Yes I by merging (combining) similar classes I mean what you have written. Is is possible. When writing CSS with dynamic languages like SASS or LESS (using MIXIS) it is likely to have some overrides of mixis's properties for particular css selector. So after compilation you can easily have two "width" or "background" attributes for one selector in compiled css, but only last attribute will have an effect. Well if you write clear CSS on your own without any ontop CSS frameworks this problem is not so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... the [yahoo compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#using) is the most robust one IMHO